# Filtering a list by regex in python does not work with single quotes

Tags: python, scrapy

I am extracting data from a html page with xpath and want to retrieve a specific information located in a text part.

```
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="productDetails"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/text()').extract()
['\nInhalt: 10 Stück', '\nGrundpreis: 1 Stück 0,14 €']
```

This returns me the wanted info within a dictionary, alongside with several other info.

Now I try to grab the wanted info via regex, as I do not know the position, it changes. So I filter:

```
>>> r = re.compile('.*Grundpreis.*')
>>> newlist = list(filter(r.match, data))
```

Somehow this does not work and returns an empty list:

```
>>> newlist
[]
```

I followed examples found on SO which worked but this one does not. The only difference I could find is, that my example is single quotes instead of double quotes. But this seems not to be possible to change with the xpath command.

How can I extract the wanted information "Grundpreis:..." without a key index?

Comment: If you just want to test if a substring is in a string: `filter(lambda x:"Grundpreis" in x, li)` is anther way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the list of special characters in the [syntax section of the `re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `.`
>   (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.

The [`Pattern.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match) method:

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match this regular expression, return a corresponding match object. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

Since the pattern `.*Grundpreis.*` will not match the first character of the string `"\nGrundpreis: 1 Stück 0,14 €"`, as it is a newline, `match()` returns `None`.

---

Here is an example which should give you some inspiration for what you're trying to do:

```py
import re

patt = re.compile(r"Grundpreis: (.*)")

test_strs = ['\nInhalt: 10 Stück', '\nGrundpreis: 1 Stück 0,14 €']

for elem in test_strs:
    res = patt.search(elem)
    if res:
        print(f"Match found in string: {elem}. Match: {res}. Group: {res.group(1)}")
    else:
        print(f"No match in string: {elem}")
```

Output:

```
No match in string: 
Inhalt: 10 Stück
Match found in string: 
Grundpreis: 1 Stück 0,14 €. Match: <re.Match object; span=(1, 27), match='Grundpreis: 1 Stück 0,14 €'>. Group: 1 Stück 0,14 €
```